# Angular how to inspect formData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multipartform-data, form-data

I declared a form data like this:   `public data: FormData = new FormData();`. I'm trying to inspect it. The problem is that I try with `console.log(data)` and also with data.entries():

```
for (let pair of data.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

but I get this error: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'FormData'. How can I inspect it?

Comment: Looks like you're declaring your variable wrong.

Comment: I would make sure you're declaring your form data object before calling `.entries()` on it. If you're executing declaration and logging in different angular hooks, I'd google the order they are executed. If you're executing both declaration and logging in the same function, I would review [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries). Otherwise, not certain how I can help